# What is the most accurate way to convert org.joda.time.LocalDateTime to java.time.LocalDateTime in scala?

Tags: java, scala, datetime, jodatime

I have output of a library function that returns a random `org.joda.time.LocalDateTime` in the future that needs to be converted to `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

What is the most efficient way to do this without losing accuracy in Scala?

Comment: Scala or Java doesn't matter for this question at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.time.ZoneId

val jodaLocalDateTime = org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.now()
val javaLocalDateTime = java.time.LocalDateTime.ofInstant(jodaLocalDateTime.toDate.toInstant, ZoneId.systemDefault())
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the javadoc of both, then find a way to create a [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) from the getter methods of [`org.joda.time.LocalDateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html).

First, realize that `org.joda.time.LocalDateTime` don't support nano-second precision:

> Internally, LocalDateTime uses a single **millisecond-based value** to represent the local datetime. This value is only used internally and is not exposed to applications.

So, to create a `java.time.LocalDateTime`, use [`LocalDateTime.of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hour, int minute, int second, int nanoOfSecond)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-int-int-int-int-int-int-int-).

To get the values from `org.joda.time.LocalDateTime`, use:

```
getYear()
getMonthOfYear()
getDayOfMonth()
getHourOfDay()
getMinuteOfHour()
getSecondOfMinute()
getMillisOfSecond()
```

It's really that simple: **Read the documentation.**